# What causes the terrible FPS drop in CS:GO and why does `logadress_add 1` solve it?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, performance

Sometimes in a match on Faceit, my fps drop from ~300 to 20. Opening the ingame console and typing "logadress_add 1" will freeze my game for 3-5 seconds and afterwards my fps are back to normal. What is happening and why does the command help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command is only one of many possible solutions to temporarily fix the fps bug.

`logaddress_add xy` does nothing to the game itself. It is used for adding external hosts to the game. These hosts will receive a live game log (such as Go TV or client software like HLSW).

- So why does it work?

It causes a small lag. This lag temporarily "fixes" the bug. That's about it.

- Don't other commands cause lag too?

Yep. And they work just fine. You could as well start/stop recording a demo, change graphic settings or whatever you can think of to cause a small lag. Most of them will work too.